# How to assign values to an array

Tags: c#

I am trying to assign invalid characters to an array and then call a function that checks if an entered string from a text box has the invalid characters from the array in it.

```
string[] invalidchars = new string[3] ("!", "@","#",)
```

I keep getting an error under string that says `string is a class type and cannot be used as an expression`

Comment: That code is not valid vb.net :)

Comment: Nor is it valid c#.  What language do you want this in?

Comment: Why is this being upvoted? This is clearly just a [RTFM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453(v=vs.71).aspx) issue. Had OP actually looked at any examples or documentation, they'd see this is just not how to declare a string array.

Comment: Try looking on Google for some tutorials on C# or vb.net or whatever language that is supposed to be.  This is a really basic issue and can be easily solved through research on your own.

Comment: He's trying to declare it using C# syntax, but initialize it using VB.NET syntax! Kinda funny!

Answer (score 8):

Your syntax needs a few fixes.  Here's the correct version.

```
string[] invalidchars = new string[] { "!", "@", "#" };
```

Primarily, you need to use { } instead of ( ).

Comment: I believe tkey most important piece here is the {} initialization (he had parentheses), perhaps this should be called out?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET That is true. Updated.

Comment: Not from me, I think this answer is great as is.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to replace your paranthesis with curve braces and remove comma:

```
string[] invalidchars = new string[3] {"!", "@", "#"};
```

but the shortest way to do it would be:

```
var invalidchars = new[] {"!", "@", "#"};
```

By values of array C# compiler can infer the type of array.